# Проверка типа данных ячейки в таблице HTML с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<table id="t">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>m</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Как проверить, что в ячейке лежит число или нет с помощью javascript?

Answer (score 2):

```js
var cellValue1 = document.getElementById("t").rows[0].cells[0].textContent;
console.log("0,0 -", isNaN(cellValue1) ? "not a number" : "number", cellValue1);
var cellValue2 = document.getElementById("t").rows[0].cells[1].textContent;
console.log("0,1 -", isNaN(cellValue2) ? "not a number" : "number", cellValue2);
```

```html
<table id="t">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>m</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>f</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const data = document.querySelectorAll('td');

data.forEach((item) => console.log(isNaN(item.innerText) ? 'не число' : 'число'));
```

```html
<table id="t">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>m</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```